# Handling user input with different amount of characters in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to program a Streets and Alleys card game with Python and I'm having some trouble handling when the user input is a single-character string, or a 3-character string, and if it is a 3-character string, check the two ints with the input. So here is what my menu looks like to start:

```
Input options:
    MTT s d: Move card from Tableau pile s to Tableau pile d.
    MTF s d: Move card from Tableau pile s to Foundation d.
    MFT s d: Move card from Foundation s to Tableau pile d.
    U: Undo the last valid move.
    R: Restart the game (after shuffling)
    H: Display this menu of choices
    Q: Quit the game
```

Essentially, the input will be made into a list, then check to see if their first index of the option list is U, R, H, or Q, if so, then do what that says. If the first index of the option list is 3 characters long, check if it is MTT, MTF, or MFT. I then need to check if the second index of the list (s) is between 0 and 7, then it's valid. Same for the third index of the list (d), but between 0 and 3. Here is my code now:

```
def get_option():
    '''Prints option menu and takes
    user input to determine which 
    option will follow'''
    while True:
        
        option = str(input("\nInput an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): ")).lower()
        
        
        option_list = option.split()
        
        mxx = ["mtt", "mtf", "mft"]
        
        for item in option_list:
            mode = str(item[0])
            if len(mode) == 1:
                for c in mode:
                    if c == "u":
                        option_list[0] = c.upper()
                        return option_list
                    
                    if c == "r":
                        option_list[0] = c.upper()
                        return option_list
                    
                    if c == "h":
                        option_list[0] = c.upper()
                        return option_list
                    
                    if c == "q":
                        option_list[0] = c.upper()
                        return option_list
                    
                    else:
                        print("Error in option:", option_list[0])
                        return None
                    continue

                
            if mode not in mxx:
                return None
            else:
                return option_list
            
            source = int(item[1])
            if 7 > source > 0:
                print("Error in Source.")
                return None
            else:
                return option_list
            
            destination = int(item[2])
            if 3 > destination > 0:
                print("Error in Destination")
                return None
            else:
                return option_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what this function is supposed to return, but at least some parts of it seem to be operating under the idea that it's returning validated input as a list of strings, and continuing to prompt until the input validates successfully, so I'll write it under that assumption:

```
def get_option():
    '''Prints option menu and takes
    user input to determine which 
    option will follow'''
    while True:
        option = input("\nInput an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): ").upper().split()
        if not option:
            continue
        cmd = option[0]
        if cmd not in (
            "MTT", "MTF", "MFT", "U", "R", "H", "Q"
        ):
            print(f"Invalid option {cmd}")
            continue
        if cmd in ("U", "R", "H", "Q"):
            if len(option) == 1:
                return option
            print(f"Option {cmd} does not take extra parameters.")
            continue
        if len(option) != 3:
            print(f"Option {cmd} expects 2 additional parameters.")
            continue
        try:
            if int(option[1]) not in range(8):
                raise ValueError("Source is out of range 0-7.")
            if int(option[2]) not in range(4):
                raise ValueError("Destination is out of range 0-3.")
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            continue
        else:
            return option
```

```
>>> get_option()

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): Q 2
Option Q does not take extra parameters.

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): MTT
Option MTT expects 2 additional parameters.

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): foo
Invalid option FOO

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): mtt 0 10
Destination is out of range 0-3.

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): mtt 10 2
Source is out of range 0-7.

Input an option (MTT,MTF,MFT,U,R,H,Q): mtt 2 3
['MTT', '2', '3']
```

Each possible way that the input might be invalid leads to a `continue` which causes the loop to repeat and try again.  Each way that the input might be valid leads to a `return`.

Note that rather than converting the input to `lower()` and then back to `upper()` before returning it, I just converted it to `upper()` up front, which has the same effect but involves fewer steps and is IMO less confusing.

Comment: If the input is not of the required form, the function prints an error message "Error in option:" followed by the option entered by the user and returns None. Note that input with the incorrect number of arguments, e.g. M 2, or incorrect types, e.g. F D, will return None. If the indices are not valid, the function should return None. Valid indices are integers within the corresponding range. If the index for the source is not valid an error in source message "Error in Source." should be printed and the function should return None. Same for destination.

Comment: Why the `while True` in your original code if the idea isn't to re-prompt on invalid input?